# Widget Framework using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, drag-and-drop, widget

In my project, I need to build an iGoogle like page. The page will have multiple drag-drop widgets and each widget is a separate application.

Any advise/links?

Comment: I suggest you post a more concrete problem. The question is too abstract and can be solved by Google search.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quite simply, yes, there is [a project](https://github.com/petrkotek/angular-widgetarea-directive) that does this.

The project allows you to create a `widgetarea` using a directive. This should have the base functionality you need.

In the future, you can google for this sort of thing. It took me 30 seconds.

[image: Screenshot]